# Should I tell my boss if he asks that I will go to another company interview?

Tags: interviewing

Lets say I am invited to another company interview. As I see often the interviewers call you to come at normal working hours.

So then they assume that most companies can lets the worker go somewhere else during work time and worker might work those couple of hours at another not usual time.

But when you tell the boss you need to go, he usually ask why. So the question is how you should tell?

Or another situation - you got a phone call during work, you answer, and your boss asks - what did they offer or something like that. What do you have to tell?

I think lying is bad for your reputation and moral things.

Thinking logically - you have a right to check what you are worth. So there should be nothing bad to go to interview.

But I am thinking that it might be scary for the boss when you tell that some other company might be interested in you. On the other hand if the company is giving you value what you are worth then they should not be scary, if they are giving less than you are worth, then they need to fix the problem in themselves.

Comment: I have been in such situations which I described but does it make a difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Some interviewing companies are willing to hold out-of-hours interviews, or at least schedule you early or late in the working day to help you out. Of course, sometimes, it can't be done - but you can always ask:

"Hi, I'm really sorry, but it is actually hard for me to take time out of my working day where I currently work. Would it be possible to have the interview later in the day - preferably 5.30, but anytime after 4 would be acceptable."

2. Your boss doesn't need to know why you need to duck out - "personal business" is personal. For all he knows, you could be going to the bank, seeing the doctor, sorting something out - many things cannot be done outside of office hours. If your boss asks - don't lie, but also don't tell him the specific reason. If he presses, just say "it's personal and I really don't want to discuss it".

And, as you say in your question, offer to make up the time some other time - "hey, boss - I'm sorry but I have to duck out early next Tuesday for personal business, but if I stay back late on Wednesday and Thursday I can get my tasks done".

Comment: ok. What if you are friendly with boss and usually telling lot of personal things? And then suddenly out of nowhere you say its personal. Then he might easily guess why it is :)

Comment: He might guess, he might know, and if he's the kind of boss you often share personal things with, he might even be OK with it or prepare a counterproposal. But the golden rule remains: **don't tell your current employer you're looking for a new job until you have a firm offer (on paper, only missing your signature) from another company.**

Comment: @SPeed_FANat1c: There are personal things, and there are PERSONAL things. Even if we were close friends and I know lots of personal stuff about you, it wouldn't surprise me if you told me something was too personal to tell me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't "duck out" - take a holiday (day or half day)

If you nip out of work for an hour or two, you're asking something of a favour from your boss/company. Not only is this a little unfair, as they're doing you a favour to help you leave them, it's also more likely to raise questions: your boss may have to justify to *his* boss why someone is out, or may need a reasonable reason to justify it. This flexibility is usually given to allow people to attend Doctor or Dentist appointments, or deal with childcare or health issues: not to go for an interview.

If you take a holiday, you're doing things on your own time, and what you do is your own business. It also gives you more time to prepare for the interview, improving your chances of success.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, an employee is able to take personal hours up to an half-our basis. This is great combined with a good excuse "e.g. I need to go bank to replace my malfunctioning ATM card"

Comment: Errata corrige: it is a combination of jurisdiction **and** work environment. Contract law may allow 1-hour windows of personal time, company may break it in half-hours

Comment: An hour is nowhere near long enough to attend an interview even nearby

Comment: Of course, I just meant the employee can take 2 or 2.5 hours of personal time. Normally better take the whole afternoon (as in the morning you may be tight in time to return to office after lunch)